# pywinauto save (permant) control identifiers to variable

Tags: python, automation, pywinauto

I am trying to save control identifiers to a variable.
The reason is that: i use `main_dlg.print_control_identifiers(filename="control_ids.text")` but i am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_tests.py", line 7, in <module>
    main_dlg.print_control_identifiers(filename="control_ids.text")
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 696, in prin
t_control_identifiers
    print_identifiers([this_ctrl, ], log_func=log_func)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 685, in prin
t_identifiers
    print_identifiers(ctrl.children(), current_depth + 1, log_func)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 681, in prin
t_identifiers
    log_func(output)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 694, in log_
func
    log_file.write(str(msg) + os.linesep)
  File "C:\python\lib\codecs.py", line 721, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "C:\python\lib\codecs.py", line 377, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
  File "C:\python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 71-76: c
haracter maps to <undefined>
```

because the program i am trying to control has greek characters inside.

So, i decided to save the control identifiers to a variable and then save it with the right encoding to a txt file.

A simple solution i thought is:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import os

app = Application(backend="uia").start("C:/python/Lib/site-packages/QtDesigner/designer.exe")
main_dlg = app.QtDesigner
main_dlg.wait('visible')
main_dlg.print_control_identifiers()
```

and then:

```
python script_name.py > output.txt
```

after that in output.txt file there are the control identifiers of the program (in this example QtDesigner).

Comment: It should be fixed in `atspi` branch, but it's not released yet.